# Thinkpad T60 is Thinkpad T43?

Tags: thinkpad

I recently  bought a refurbished T60 Lenovo Thinkpad.
I have had a few problems with it and have gotten good help here.

Now, however, as I was trying to follow up on of the answers I got, I found out that, contrary to the case markings, when I go to System in the Control Panel it displays as a T43.

Have I been mislead or is the t43 of the t60 family?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A google for Txx specs shows that the T60 has 3 USB ports and the T42 has 2. Which does yours have?

Links to Notebook Review for other specification differences. Look for graphics and screen. One of the links shows weight (the other doesn't, that I can see.)
[T42](http://www.notebookreview.com/default.asp?newsID=2520)
[T60](http://www.notebookreview.com/default.asp?newsID=2702)

Comment: 3 USB.

I should have refered to the t43, not t42.

Comment: The 43 has 2 USB ports. So 3 USBs is some evidence for yours being a T60. How do the other specs differences look?

Comment: Look-wise, it conforms to the t60, but there is a discrepancy between the case and the system information.

Comment: On consulting the place I bought it, this is a branding issue by the retailer. It is a T60.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The "T43" indication you are seeing in the system information may be branded in there.  At least when I look in the system information on my T60p I do not see anything indicating my laptop's model.

Maybe Lenovo used a similar disk imaging process for the T60 as they did with the T43 and just missed replacing "T43" with "T60" in a few spots during early production.

Or maybe the operating system was reinstalled using a T43 recovery disc, although I'm not sure if that is even possible.

Answer (score 1):

Thinkpad laptops indeed often have this "identity crisis", what the control panel thinks is unreliable. If someone wants to find out which laptop he has, looking at the location of the ports is a useful one, and should seriously narrow down the options. After that, the processor model should be enough to uniquely figure out which laptop you have.

I think the reason for this "identity crisis"  is that Lenovo does not replace all the parts when they make a new laptop. My old R61i was part T61 and part T60 according to my tries in the Linux command line.